# DateTime POSTed to controller turns null in azure while works in development environment

Tags: c#, datetime, azure, asp.net-mvc-5

I encountered an odd problem in my MVC5 web app, that occurs only in azure and I was hoping someone here can help me out.

I have a form with fields FromDate and ToDate, which are POSTed to a controller. Dates are formatted to "dd.MM.yyyy". When I run the code in Visual Studio I get the correct values in the controller, but when deployed in azure the controller receives values 01.01.0001, which is the default date when a datetime object appears null.

I think the problem may be that my date format is not recognized as a datetime and they are replaced with default values instead of producing an error. I have to keep the date format in the ui and I think scripting the date format at clientside before POSTing is not the correct way to go so I'm looking for better options, preferably a fix to the problem instead of just avoiding the problem by sending strings and parsing them on server side.

Here's my clientside form using razor:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <p>
        <input type="text" id="FromDate" name="FromDate" value="@(Model.StartDate.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy"))">
        <input type="text" id="ToDate" name="ToDate" value="@(Model.EndDate.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy"))">
    </p>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
}
```

Here's the controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult MyController(MyInputObject input)
{
    // Do something with input.FromDate and input.ToDate
}
```

And this is my MyInputObject:

```
public class MyInputObject
{
    public DateTime FromDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime ToDate { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Azure uses `en-US` culture thus dates must be formatted using `MM-dd-yyyy` format. Could this error is coming because of that?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I think the problem is. However my users are not US americans and I must display dates in their preferred format. There must be some kind of configuration in either VS or in Azure, I don't believe Azure is not capable of serving other cultures. I wonder how global web apps with multiple cultures can be made in Azure...

Comment: This culture stuff confuses me a lot as well :P. Servers running under Azure are your standard Windows Servers running standard ASP.NET/.Net framework so it fully supports setting appropriate culture. The question is how do you deal with people using your application from different countries where each country has their own localization scheme.

Comment: Have a look at the answer given by Arun in this [SO thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13858120/currency-settings-in-azure). He explains how to change the current culture for an Azure site using, for example, `web.config`. This might help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found it, the application's culture can be set in web.config under  element like this:

```
<globalization enableClientBasedCulture="true" uiCulture="fi-FI" culture="fi-FI"/>
```

It does not answer how multicultural web apps are made but solves my problem.

Thanks Gaurav Mantri and Jason Evans for your comments, they got me on the right track!