# Datetime changes to US when published on server

Tags: c#, datetime, azure

I have these two methods that I use to populate a select list of dates. When I test this locally it's all fine but when I publish the website to the azure server(which is supposed to be European) the times displayed are in the American format.

```
public class DateItem
{
    public DateTime Value { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
}

public static DateTime FirstDateOfWeek(int weekno, int yearno)
    {
        CultureInfo uk = new CultureInfo("en-GB");

        DateTime jan1 = new DateTime(yearno, 1, 1);
        int daysOffset = DayOfWeek.Thursday - jan1.DayOfWeek;

        DateTime firstThursday = jan1.AddDays(daysOffset);
        var cal = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Calendar;
        int firstWeek = cal.GetWeekOfYear(firstThursday, CalendarWeekRule.FirstFourDayWeek, DayOfWeek.Monday);

        var weekNum = weekno;
        if (firstWeek <= 1)
        {
            weekNum -= 1;
        }
        var result = firstThursday.AddDays(weekNum * 7);
        return result.AddDays(-3);
    }

    public void GetWeekDates(int weekno, int yearno) //set date for specific week/year
    {            
        weekDates = new List<DateItem>();
        // Get the week dates based on the current week
        var day = FirstDateOfWeek(weekno, yearno);
        DateItem dateItem;
        for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
        {
            dateItem = new DateItem();
            dateItem.Text = day.AddDays(i).ToShortDateString();
            dateItem.Value = day.AddDays(i).Date;

            weekDates.Add(dateItem);
        }
        entryDate = day.Date;
    }
```

I would like to be able to maybe format my the datetimes here to be european so that no matter where I publish the code the time format will be forced to european.

When I check the html for the check list when published I get.

```
<option value="10/5/2015 12:00:00 AM">10/5/2015</option>
```

An when I test locally I get.

```
<option selected="selected" value="05/10/2015 00:00:00">05/10/2015</option>
```

Both from the same database.

Comment: Where are you writing out the `<option>` element?

Comment: Have you tried the fixes described here; 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13858120/currency-settings-in-azure

Comment: Also, why don't you specify your desired culture in your call to `ToShortDateString()`?

Comment: `@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.NewEntry.entryDate, new SelectList(Model.NewEntry.weekDates, "Value", "Text"),
         "", new { id = "entryDate", @class = "form-control" })`

Comment: After testing out a few things changing the culture in the webconfig worked best. Thanks @Matt

Comment: @EricColgan - Please post a proper answer if you've figured it out (vs in comments), so that you can properly close this question out. Also, when you added your additional info with details of your option element, that should have been an edit to your question, not as a comment.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was resolved by permanently changing the culture of the app.

```
<system.web>
    <globalization uiCulture="en-GB" culture="en-GB" />
</system.web>
```

This keeps all my DateTimes in European format throughout the app